# Android. How to check if in-app billing supported for user?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

Is there a way to check from code is in-app billing supported for user?

My app is free but i want to do some monetization. But due Google Play limitation when i enable in-app purchases users from countries without billing support can't get new versions. 
So i want to detect such situation and suggest them switch to separate free version.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/versions.html, check: isBillingSupported()

Comment: Thank you. I saw it. But billing can be unsupported due various reasons. I can't find status code that explicitly tells me billing is unsupported because of country limitation.

Comment: Is it like you want to sell the product in few places for a price and in other places for free

Comment: @war_Hero No. In most countries my app will have in-app shop and for those where billing is not supported shop wont be at all(with all items it has).